# How do i format "message.content" on a discord bot?

Tags: discord.js, formatting

i want to format what my discord bot is saying but with "message.content"

for example, if you were typing normally in discord and you wanted to, for example, make it a code chunk, you'd go "`insert message here`", but when I try to do it with the "message.content" command, it doesn't work, since it turns it into text,

message.channel.send(`message.content`)

```js
    if(client.on) {
        client.once('message', function (message) {
          if (message.content.startsWith("||tb ")) {
              message.channel.send(message.content)
          }
        }); 
    }
```

the "``"s in this case are meant to make it a code chunk

is there any way around this?

Comment: Your question is currently unclear. Are you asking about how you can remove the **boldness** and *italicness* from the post and get `**boldness** and *italicness*`?

Comment: Hi JoshM, could you show us what you tried, a code sample, an error, and maybe further details. Thanks.

Comment: Is this discord.js or discord.py, please make sure you put your question in the correct category.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the user's message and then repost it as a code block, you can use [Formatters](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Formatters) to do that. All you have to do is get the user's message and then repost it by doing this:

```js
const { Formatters } = require('discord.js')
// ...
client.on('message', function (message) {
    if (message.content.startsWith("||tb ")) {
        message.channel.send(Formatters.codeBlock(message.content))
    }
});
// ...
```

You can also additionally provide which language the code would be in also to the `Formatter`. If you want to learn more about the `.codeBlock()`, you can go here => [codeBlock | Formatters](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Formatters?scrollTo=s-codeBlock)

---

**Easier Solution**

An easier solution to format the message content would be to use triple backticks like this ```. Then, additionally if you want to specify the programming language as well you can just add it after the triple backticks. An example:

````js
client.on('message', function (message) {
    if (message.content.startsWith("||tb ")) {
        message.channel.send('```' + message.content + '```')
    }
});
````